# Bad throughput for single tcp connections

Tags: tcp

I have a server with a Gigabit Uplink, and testing with `iperf3` with 100 parallel connections i get at least 600 MBit/s, depending on the other server (i tried some public test servers).
But when i run `iperf3` with one connection i get `10-15 MBit/s`, with two `20-30 MBit/s` and so on.

I do not have very complicated iptables rules and no other idea, why it is so slow. What can be the limiting factor for single tcp connections, that they are 10 times slower than the possible bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the problem.

I had some flask webapp, which uses redis to stream events to the user. When the user disconnected, the app kept the redis pubsub connection alive, without reading data anymore.

This leads to a long `Send-Q`/`Recv-Q`, which apparently cause the tcp stack to slow down and produce kernel warnings:
"[TCP: out of memory -- consider tuning tcp_mem](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2011/03/out-of-socket-memory.html)".

- Short term fix: Kill the processes with the long packet queues.
- Long term solution: Fixing the misbehaving programs.

Answer (score 0):

Single TCP sessions are limited by the size of each sessions' window, which represents the maximum number of bytes that can be "in flight" between the two endpoints at any given time. So if you have high latency on your link, you can reach a per-session limit which is windowSize / RTT.

The only way around this (since you usually can't do a whole lot about RTT) is either to use more sessions, or to significantly increase the window size using window scaling. I don't know what iPerf's settings are relative to that, or if you might have a firewall or other filter between the endpoints that prevents the scaling even if iPerf and your server both support it.

Comment: It's a standard debian linux and it seems to have window autoscaling turned on. I noticed the problem first with plain http, iperf is for debugging. It ran more smooth before, i do not know what happend or what i changed, that it now doesn't work. I think it may be a problem in the data center, but i cannot reboot right now and without booting a recovery system for more tests, they cannot test it. So i am trying what i can do to find out more while the server keeps running.

Comment: Could you grab a packet trace? That would at least confirm whether or not it is a window-related effect.

Comment: I made a dump of some ``cat /dev/urandom | nc -lp 2000`` and ``nc host 2000 >/dev/null`` on the other side for 30 seconds and with < 1 MB/s, where like 10-20 should be possible. What should i now look for?

Comment: After maintenance downtime, tests by staff which did not give anything and a kernel update it now has the full throughput again. I do not know, what the problem was.